# Accessing sub doccuments from array in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

this is my sampale mongo doc.

```
"Notification" : [
        {
            "date_from" : ISODate("2013-06-30T18:30:00Z"),
            "date_too" : ISODate("2013-07-23T18:30:00Z"),
            "description" : "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
            "url" : "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
        },
        {
            "date_from" : ISODate("2013-07-07T18:30:00Z"),
            "date_too" : ISODate("2013-07-16T18:30:00Z"),
            "description" : "ddd",
            "url" : "ddd"
        },
        {
            "date_from" : ISODate("2013-07-02T18:30:00Z"),
            "date_too" : ISODate("2013-07-29T18:30:00Z"),
            "description" : "cccc",
            "url" : "cccccccccccccc"
        }
    ],
```

I am trying to access "Notifications":array having 3 sub documents. I want to retrieve each document individually. 
My java code is

```
notification=(BasicDBList) f.curr().get("Notification");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BasicDBList` extends `BasicBSONList`, which in turn, extends `ArrayList`. You can get individual elements from the list using their index.

```
BasicDBList notifications = (BasicDBList) cursor.curr().get("Notification");

BasicDBObject first = (BasicDBObject) notifications.get(0); //first document
BasicDBObject second = (BasicDBObject) notifications.get(1); //second document
BasicDBObject third = (BasicDBObject) notifications.get(2); //third document

System.out.println(first.get("description")); // bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
System.out.println(second.get("url")); // bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

You may instead want to iterate over them:

```
for(Object o : notifications) {
  BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) o;
  System.out.println(obj.get("url")); //prints the URL of every document in notifications
}
```